# Use Memcached in Yii2 with multiple databases/applications in the same server

Tags: php, caching, server, yii2, memcached

I'm using Memcached to store the RBAC permissions on my application, and it has been working fine for a while.

However, now I will have multiple applications with different databases in the same server, and I have experienced conflicts between the applicattions because they all use the same Memcached instance. Is there a way to create a separated Memcached instance for every application?

Comment: when you say different `applications` are you referring to the one like `frontend` `backend` or totally a different setup of yii

Comment: I'm not using the advanced template, so they are differents setups of Yii.

Comment: To avoid the cache key conflicts, you could try to prefix your Memcached keys with the application name e.g. if two different applications (**app1** & **app2**) are having the same key in Memcached, lets say: `myKey`, then you could store them in the same Memcached server as: `app1:myKey` and `app2:myKey`.

Comment: How is your memcached configured currently (in main.php or main-local.php)?